# How to fix this error i am getting on installing express by writing npm install express --save on vs code terminal.i am trying to install on E

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

npm install express -- save
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path E:
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ankit Kumar Sharma\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-02T11_12_21_744Z-debug-0.log

i tried many things but cant solve it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run the following npm command, 'npm install --force express --save'

Answer (score 0):

As error states operation is rejected by operating system as you have lack of permissions. Try with sudo it will work.

```
sudo npm install express
```